# JSON into Options of a Input Select

Tags: javascript, json, select

I have a string of json that I'm trying to put into the options of my select input field. I'd like the Type_label to go in the Type_lable and the value to be the type number.

Here is my json:

```
var serviceCODES = [{
"type_label": "Medical Care",
"type": "1",

}, {
"type_label": "Surgical",
"type": "2",

}, {
"type_label": "Consultation",
"type": "3",

}]
```

Here is my html and js

```
 <select id="datas" name="datas" >

 <script>
    var $select = $('#datas');

    $.each(serviceCODES, function(i, val){
        $select.append($('<option />', { value: (i+1), text: val[i+1] }));
     });
 </script>
```

For some reason this isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$select.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + val.type_label + '</option>');
```

In those cases, when you're confusing of how retrieve data in a loop, always take a look on arguments provided by the function(I always use this):

`console.log(arguments);`

Comment: If you want the `value` attribute to be the `type` parameter of your object, use `val.type` instead of `i`.

Comment: This is great! This totally worked thanks! I'll approve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.each(serviceCODES, function(i, val){
    $select.append($('<option />', { value: (i+1), text: val.type_label}));
});
```

`$.each()` passes current index and **item** to the callback function. You tried to access elements of `val` by index. Also you probably want to access some property of `val`.